# HTLM5 File Input directly to browser cache (no upload/server)

Tags: javascript, json, html

I want to allow the user to import/export his own preferences as a small (Json) file ; Once validated, I would replace the values already stored in [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) by the ones in the file.

Consider that a lot of this [HTML5 File Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) feature proof of concept demos use images and allow **previewing them in the browser before the actual upload**! If the browser can read and render an image, surely it can read my small 30 lines Json file, right? That's *exactly* what I want to do.

I don't need a web server for that, I want the file to *stay on the client side the whole time* ; How can I do that?

Comment: So you want to allow a client to select a file (JSON) format, load/preview it and update the record in the local storage?

Comment: use `FileReader()`'s `.readAsText()` method, then `JSON.parse()` the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can read files using FileReader like this,

```
<input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'>

var openFile = function (event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        var text = reader.result;
        obj = JSON.parse(text);
        obj_database = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("..."));
        //change obj_database
        localStorage.setItem("...", JSON.stringify(obj_database));
        //print success msg
    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```